Postgres - conditional queries for report
Let's say we have two tables - plan and foreign_exchange
Plan schema is
CREATE TABLE plan
( 
    plan_id              UUID  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    display_name         VARCHAR(100),
    plan_currency        VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    amount               NUMERIC(22, 10)
);

foreign_exchange schema is
CREATE TABLE foreign_exchange_rates 
(
  id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tenant_id UUID NOT NULL,
  entity_id VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  from_currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  to_currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  effective_date DATE NOT NULL,
  conversion_rate DECIMAL(10,5) NOT NULL
);


Requirement: create report on plan. What it translates into is as below:
Let's say plan has only one entry



plan_id
display_name
plan_currency
amount




1
Plan_for_us
USD
100



Actually when report is generated following is the expectation:



plan_id
display_name
plan_currency
amount




1
Plan_for_us
USD
100


1
Plan_for_us
INR
8500


1
Plan_for_us
GBP
80


1
Plan_for_us
AUD
155



If the plan_currency exists in foreign_exchange_rates as from_currency, we should have additional entries (original entry should exists anyway) in the report with amount as converted amount taking conversion rate into consideration.
====================Update as of 24-July-2024==================
For some people who thought I did not put in any effort before posting this question. My query is as complex as the query below:
WITH ccr AS (SELECT DISTINCT ON (from_currency, to_currency) *
         FROM foreign_exchange_rates
         WHERE effective_date <= current_timestamp AND 
is_overridden = false
         ORDER BY from_currency, to_currency, effective_date DESC)

SELECT

prd.product_id AS "Product ID",
prd.external_id AS "Product External ID",
prd.name AS "Product Name",
prd.description AS "Product Description",
prd.sku as "Product SKU",
category.name AS "Product Category",
plan.plan_id AS "Plan ID",
plan.external_id as "Plan External ID",
plan.name AS "Plan Name",
plan.description AS "Plan Description",
plan.status AS "Plan Status",
ccr.to_currency AS "Currency",
chrg.charge_id AS "Charge ID",
chrg.external_id AS "Charge External ID",
chrg.name AS "Charge Name",
chrg.description AS "Charge Description",
chrg.charge_type AS "Charge Type",
chrg.charge_model AS "Charge Model",
chrg.cycle AS "Charge Cycle",
chrg.percent AS "Charge Percent",
chrg.amount * ccr.conversion_rate AS "Charge Amount",
chrg.is_custom AS "Is Custom Charge",
chrg.is_renewable AS "Is Renewable",
chrg.min_quantity AS "Charge Minimum Quantity",
chrg.max_quantity AS "Charge Maximum Quantity",
chrg.default_quantity AS "Charge Default Quantity",
chrg.duration_in_months AS "Duration In Months",
chrg.price_tiers AS "Charge Price Tiers",
chrg.rate_card_id as "Rate Card Id",
rtc.name as "Rate Card Name"

FROM product prd
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_category category
                     ON <some condition> 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN plan
                     ON <some condition>
     LEFT OUTER JOIN charge chrg
                     ON <some condition>
     LEFT OUTER JOIN rate_card rtc
                     ON <some condition>
     LEFT JOIN ccr
                     ON <some condition>

 WHERE <some condition> AND prd.is_deleted = FALSE
 ORDER BY prd.name

Since the query was involving 6 tables, I simplified the question by just mentioning about 2 tables.

Have you even tried anything???

@Eric I am not sure what was the intention behind your question, I have added more details to my post. I hope that will clarify your doubts.

There is no intention.  People can't help you fix your query if you don't even post it.

You can use UNION ALL command to acheive the result:
SELECT plan_id, display_name, plan_currency, amount FROM plan
UNION ALL
SELECT plan_id, display_name, to_currency, amount * conversion_rate amount
FROM plan
JOIN foreign_exchange_rates ON foreign_exchange_rates.from_currency = plan.plan_currency;

Try the SQL on fiddle
Result:
|--------------------------------------|--------------|---------------|----------------------|
| plan_id                              | display_name | plan_currency | amount               |
|--------------------------------------|--------------|---------------|----------------------|
| 10d787ad-68e4-4dc5-8802-8baa473433ca | paln_for_us  | USD           | 100.0000000000       |
| 10d787ad-68e4-4dc5-8802-8baa473433ca | paln_for_us  | AUD           | 155.000000000000000  |
| 10d787ad-68e4-4dc5-8802-8baa473433ca | paln_for_us  | GBP           | 80.000000000000000   |
| 10d787ad-68e4-4dc5-8802-8baa473433ca | paln_for_us  | INR           | 8500.000000000000000 |


Thanks @Slava Rozhnev. is it possible to select some columns from foreign_exchange_rates as well?

plan_currency is always USD which is wrong. as in USD the amount is always 100.

I fixed the answer.

Thanks a ton. As I updated my post, my use case is really really complex.
